# How to generate test-output folder from testng tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, testng

How to generate the test-output folder for a testNG test?

I am trying to get the default testng report, index.html

Netbeans7/windows7

I made a simple testng test case, ran it in netbeans 7, and here is the result.  I see no test-output.  I am displaying the project and file structure.

If I need to do something with ant or maven, please describe VERY detailed steps as to how to proceed on Windows 7 -- I am new to both of those tools.

If I need to do something with build.xml, please give explicit, detailed steps

[image: netbeans testng output and project file structure]

EDIT:

here is a screenshot of my final netbeans layout, including the TestSuite.xml file that got the results folder to generate:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the report files (HTML & XML) are written to a folder named `test-output` under your workspace.

Netbeans however overrides this location. It places output to `build/test/results` folder. Please re-run the **TestNG test suite** and watch results folder. All required files will be generated there.

If you want to tinker with the output location open file `nbproject/project.properties` under your project folder. In that file there is a property called `build.test.results.dir` which gets passed as an argument to ant task for TestNG run. I do not think you need to edit netbeans generated build files for this purpose.

Also, when you run the tests, have a look at the console(netbeans) output, there it may print messages such as :

```
[-d output-directory]
default output directory to : test-output
```

Comment: build/test/results is empty :(  and yes that is where nbproject/project.properties says it should be.  are the files/code set up right in my image?  do i need to have a suite for this to work?  i tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, please create a test suite - everything else looks fine.

Comment: thank you!  my TestSuite.xml was wrong in earlier failed attempts

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using **IntelliJ** and that's how I fixed it:

Select **Use default reporters** under the **Listeners** tab on the Run/Debug Configurations

[image]

[image]

*PS: Remember to **add the path** for the **testng xml** file under the Suite field*